# Proving an identity of the sum of products involving binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

**My question**

Let $n \geq 2$ be a power of 2, $k = \log_2 n$ and
$$
\begin{split}
\phi_h &:= \phi_h(n, c_{h + 1}, ..., c_{k - 1}) = \frac{n}{2^{h + 1}} - \frac{1}{2^{h + 1}} \sum_{i = h + 1}^{k - 1} 2^i \cdot c_i, \quad h \in \{ 0, 1, ..., k-2 \}, \\
\phi_{k - 1} &:= 1
\end{split}
$$
I'm trying to prove that
$$
\sum_{c_0, ..., c_{k-1}} \ \prod_{h = k-1}^0 \binom{\phi_h}{c_h} 2^{c_h} = \binom{n}{t},
$$
such that
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{h = 0}^{k - 1} 2^h \cdot c_h = t < n, \\
\forall h \in \{ 0, ..., k - 1 \}, \ 0 \leq c_h \leq \phi_h.
\end{split}
$$

**My effort**

I noticed that
$$
\begin{split}
\phi_h &= \frac{n}{2^{h + 1}} - \frac{1}{2^{h + 1}} \sum_{i = h + 1}^{k - 1} 2^i \cdot c_i, \\
\phi_{h - 1} &= \frac{n}{2^h} - \frac{1}{2^h} \sum_{i = h}^{k - 1} 2^i \cdot c_i.
\end{split}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
\phi_{h - 1} &= 2 \phi_h - c_h, \\
\prod_{h = k-1}^0 \binom{\phi_h}{c_h} &= \frac{\phi_{k - 1}!}{c_{k - 1}! (\phi_{k - 1} - c_{k - 1})!} \times \frac{\phi_{k - 2}!}{c_{k - 2}! (\phi_{k - 2} - c_{k - 2})!} \times \cdots \times \frac{\phi_0!}{c_0! (\phi_0 - c_0)!} \\
&= \frac{\phi_{k - 1}!}{c_{k - 1}! (\phi_{k - 1} - c_{k - 1})!} \times \frac{({\color{red} 2}\phi_{k - 1} - c_{k - 1})!}{c_{k - 2}! (\phi_{k - 2} - c_{k - 2})!} \times \cdots \times \frac{({\color{red} 2}\phi_1 - c_1)!}{c_0! (\phi_0 - c_0)!}.
\end{split}
$$
For me, the above product is somehow similar to [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_multinomials) if the red factor 2 can be removed. I'm stuck in how to remove this factor by using the condition $\sum_{h = 0}^{k - 1} 2^h \cdot c_h = t$ and $2^{c_h}$. It would be really appreciated if you could give me any hint on this question.